# 3D Vectors and constness

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing a function which takes in 3 vectors thus:

```
mat4 lookAt(const vec3 &eye, const vec3 &centre, const vec3 &up);
```

The problem arises when I want to do some vector maths:

```
auto s = centre - eye; // won't compile
auto a = s.normalise();
```

When `s` attempts to be compiled, the compiler throws this error:

```
error: passing ‘const vec3’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

And this is how I implement subtractor overloading in my vec3 class:

```
vec3 vec3::operator -(const vec3& v)
{
    *this -= v;
    return *this;
}
```

Which ultimately comes from:

```
vec3& vec3::operator -=(const vec3& v)
{
    this->x -= v.x;
    this->y -= v.y;
    this->z -= v.z;

    return *this;
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing the compiler error to prop up, so:

1. I changed `auto` to explicit types, prefixed by const; e.g. `const vec3 a = s.normalise();`. This didn't work.
2. It could have something to do with the subtractor overload wherein it's returning a reference.

I have checked my copy constructor, and my assignment overload - they both function fine; both are used in other pieces of code and working as intended.

Just so you are also aware, the `lookAt` function is declared and implemented within the implementation file. It's neither a member of a class nor used in a header file. Might that confuse the compiler?

I need a third eye for this as I can't figure out the exact context of the error in question!

Comment: Your `operator-` is... troublesome to say the least. It is missing the `const` specifier, which would highlight the fact that, as it is written now, **it modifies the current instance** before returning the result, which is definitely unexpected. `operator-` should leave the current instance alone; the idiom of recycling `-=` works by creating a copy first, and then use `-=` on it.

Comment: Hmmm... Haven't done that in a long time, but wouldn't it be better to use a 2-parameter ´vec3& operator-(const vec3& a, const vec3& b)´ method instead?

Comment: @PMF The latter method is more functionally correct, but it leads to messy code especially when you have to handle huge numbers of operator overloads. Having the operator overloads member functions makes it easier to handle data. It runs the risk of accidentally modifying internal data though, which is the big downside.

Comment: @Poriferous I am not sure how the code would be messier with non-members than with members. If you need access to non-public data to implement them, use `friend` declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the compilation error is that `operator-` is not `const`, but you are applying it via `const` reference. Only `const` members can be applied to objects via `const` references. The signature needs to be

```
vec3 vec3::operator -(const vec3& v) const
                                     ^^^^^
```

Then you need to modify the implementation such that it doesn't modify `this`, which it should never do anyway (`a - b` should not modify `a` or `b`). For example,

```
vec3 vec3::operator -(const vec3& v) const
{
    vec3 res = *this;
    res -= v;
    return res;
}
```

Note that it is customary to implement `operator-` as a non-member, to make the treatment of RHS and LHS operands symmetric:

```
vec3 operator-(const vec3& lhs, const vec3& rhs)
{
  vec3 res = lhs;
  res -= rhs;
  return rhs;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem; it was a case the operator overload was not const-correct!

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem in the implementation of the `- operator`. In the implementation you are changing the value of `this` which not correct. when you subtract two variable, you do not change any of them. Thus leads to error because you subtracting `auto s = centre - eye;` and `centre` is `const` while the `- operator` is trying trying to edit it.

This is the right way to overload `- operator`:

```
vec3 vec3::operator -(const vec3& v) const
{
    vec3 temp;
    temp.x=this->x-v.x;
    temp.y=this->y-v.y;
    temp.z=this->z-v.z;
    return temp;
}
```